# Adding an aggregate column causing GROUP BY error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compiler-errors, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm adding an aggregate column `min(finumber)` to my query. Once I add this number I want to be able to use it in the `ORDER BY`. When I remove the `min(finumber)` the query works fine. When I add `min(finumber)` it gives me the error:

> Column 'soitem.fsono' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My question is: How am I able to add `min(finumber)` and use it to `ORDER BY` my data?

```
SELECT A.fsono,
       MAX(A.Attention) AS Attention,
       MAX(A.Address1) AS Address1,
       MAX(A.Address2) AS Address2,
       A.fcustno,
       A.fcontact,
       A.min_fin

FROM (SELECT soitem.fsono,
             somast.fcustno,
             somast.fcontact,
               min(finumber)as min_fin, 
             CASE
                  WHEN (CONVERT(varchar(MAX), soship.fmstreet)) LIKE 'ATTN%' THEN LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(MAX), soship.fmstreet), CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), CONVERT(varchar(MAX), soship.fmstreet)))
                  ELSE NULL
             END AS Attention,
             CASE WHEN [id] = 2 THEN S.val ELSE NULL END AS Address1,
             CASE WHEN [id] = 3 THEN S.val ELSE NULL END AS Address2
      FROM soitem
           INNER JOIN somast ON soitem.fsono = somast.fsono
           LEFT OUTER JOIN soship ON somast.fsono = soship.fcsono
                                 AND soship.fcenumber = ''
           CROSS APPLY [dbo].[split3](soship.fmstreet, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) S
      WHERE (somast.fstatus <> 'Cancelled')
        AND (somast.fsocoord = 'IFP'
          OR somast.fsocoord = '711')
        AND somast.fsono >= '034023') A
GROUP BY A.fsono,
         A.fcustno,
         A.fcontact
 Order by A.fsono, A.min_fin
  ;
```

Comment: I can't see `min(finumber)` anywhere in that query? Post the SQL that is causing the error, not the one that isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem here.

`min(finumber)` is in your subquery, not your main query. Your sub query doesn't have a `GROUP BY`, hence the error. You'll need to use an `OVER` clause. This is pseudo SQL, however:

```
MIN(finumber) OVER (PARTITION BY {Partition Columns}) AS min_fin
```

I would guess those columns would be `soitem.fsono, somast.fcustno, somast.fcontact`.